# Noob: Make my scripts available to me

Tags: google-apps-script

Sorry for the dumb question, I have tried to search but did not find an answer.  Please point if the answer is already been answered.

I am practicing writing my first google scripts (apps).  If I create them from within a sheet they are only available to that sheet (bound).  I can create them by creating a new script but I don't know how to make them available to all of my spreadsheets (not just one).  THe scripts I downloaded from the store show up but how do I add my scripts.

I do not want to publish these to the world, I just want them available to me so I can access them from any sheet I am working with.

Basic question but I am having trouble understanding the process.
Thanks,

Comment: You can use a "library" to make a script bound to one sheet available to other sheets.  A library is nothing more than just a script that you are using in some other Apps Script file.  You don't need to do anything to create a library.  All you do is get the Project key from the script you want to make available to your other scripts.  [Google Documentation - Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)

Comment: I was thinking using my scripts would be as easy as using the add-ons that I installed from the store. click add-on select and run.  Thanks for help and education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script bound to a spreadsheet is only available from that sheet, you won't be able to access it from another sheet.

You can also create a script file (not related to any other document) but this will not be available from sheets.

This is how it is meant to be.

One thing you can do to use functions you eventually develop in a script is to make a [Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) of it, the functions in that library will be available to other scripts if you explicitly link the new script to the library (in the script editor > ressources>library) but this procedure is not as simple as the workflow you imagine in your question : each document will have to contain a minimal piece of code that will call the script library functions.

The last option to get create a "spreadsheet-with-script" and to simply make copies of this original spreadsheet (that has a script) and that copies will have the script copied as well.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I was thinking it would show up under add-ons or if I went to get add-ons I could choose from the store or from the scripts in my google drive.   Seems I have the choice of: 
1) publishing my add-on and then adding it to my sheets so it is available under the add-on tab 
2) putting it in a library and then writing simple script per sheet to add that library to the sheet or 
3) binding the script to a "template" sheet and just copy that sheet every time I want to use it.

Thanks for the quick reply.